# compiling cxgb chelsio 10gbE driver

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling

Having trouble compiling the cxgb3toe-1.4.1.2 driver, since for some reason if i try to modprobe cxgb i get this error

`modprobe: FATAL: Module cxgb not found in directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-50-generic`

and if i try to 'make' in the cxgb src dir

````
Makefile:204: Be sure the kernel source is properly installed or try specifying the kernel source tree using 'make KSRC=<path>'
Makefile:206: *** ERROR: missing kernel source.  Stop.```

i have my headers installed for my current running kernel and am not sure what else to try, the NIC shows up via lspci but i can't get it working
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compile the cxgb module from source, you can use the in-tree
module instead.

The cxgb module is provided in the linux-modules-extra package.

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

This package really should have been installed by default, so make sure you
haven't removed any metapackages that would normally pull this in.